# Why does R convert character to factor

Tags: r

New to R and can't figure this out. I have a vector of characters, place it into a data.frame and they change to "factor":

```
> name <- c("Ann","Bob", "Carl", "Dan","Ed")  
> class(name)
    [1] "character"  # Expected this.
> wt <- c(123,234,222,199,201)
> class(wt)
    [1] "numeric"    # Expected this.   
> a <- data.frame(name, wt)
> class(a$wt)
    [1] "numeric"    # Expected this.
> class(a$name)
    [1] "factor"     # ???
```

I am not sure why this is happening.

Comment: If you look at `data.frame` function, `stringsAsFactors = default.stringsAsFactors())` which is `stringsAsFactors=TRUE`

Comment: And `default.stringsAsFactors()` is only TRUE if `getOption("stringsAsFactors")` is TRUE or NULL.  It defaults to TRUE when you open R.  It's all documented in `help(data.frame)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when creating your `data.frame`:

```
str(data.frame(name, wt, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
# 'data.frame':  5 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ name: chr  "Ann" "Bob" "Carl" "Dan" ...
#  $ wt  : num  123 234 222 199 201
```

The default behavior is for `stringsAsFactors = TRUE`. This default behavior can be changed at startup, but you may not want to do this for compatibility with other people's scripts.

Some other packages that build upon `data.frame`s have different default behavior. For instance, consider `data.table` from the "data.table" package or `data_frame` from the "dplyr" package:

```
library(data.table)
str(data.table(name, wt))
# Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  5 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ name: chr  "Ann" "Bob" "Carl" "Dan" ...
#  $ wt  : num  123 234 222 199 201
# - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 

library(dplyr)
str(data_frame(name, wt))
# Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 5 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ name: chr  "Ann" "Bob" "Carl" "Dan" ...
#  $ wt  : num  123 234 222 199 201
```

Comment: Thanks for that, didn't even cross my mind to look at settings/options.